# What is difference between SlidingTabLayout and TabLayout

Tags: android, android-tablayout

I normally use Tablayout with view pagers to create the view... but for this issue of mine [Scroll both view pager and recycler view in single scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40467343/scroll-both-view-pager-and-recycler-view-in-single-scroll) can i use https://developer.android.com/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html this.. can anyone please explain when should one use Tablayout and SlidingTabLayout. Thanks in advance.